# How to make the footer fixed through scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am setting a footer and I want it to be fixed at the bottom even if I am at the top of the page the footer is still visible

I tried using position: fixed , flex
But none of them worked

```css
footer
    {   
    margin-bottom:0px; 
        background-color: black;
        background-color:rgb(11,132,69);
        color: white; 
        
    }
```

```html
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
Some text
</footer>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or another css framework

Comment: Downvoted because not specified what was tried and what exactly didn't work -- question is unclear and/or doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: can you be more specific when you say `fixed` doesn't work??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you got to have a lot of content that is first of all scrollable and then give your footer div the following properties:

**CSS**

```
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
```

- One small note is that you got to have some content inside the footer HTML element in order for it to even render I provided the following text `A Footer!` (shown in the example below)

Other than giving a `position: fixed` you need to guide the div where to be fixed it. Its default is to be fixed top left I believe. So to have it fixed to the bottom you can add `left: 0` and `bottom: 0` to have it behave as you desire.

**Code Playground Example**

I made a small example for you to check out that is working feel free to [play around here](https://jsfiddle.net/8x14yL2g/10/) It looks like this and as you can see the scroll handle is midway through the scroll track marked in red while the footer is fixed to the bottom as you wanted it to.

**Demo**

[image]

*One Small Note*

`position: fixed` is what you desire. It will fix the divs position without being dependent on scroll event. `position: sticky` is a sort of combination of `position: relative` in default that in turn will shift to become `position: fixed` when you scroll down enough and the div will then be fixed.
- `position: sticky` is currently experimental and not supported in IE.

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding

Comment: @IslamAshraf - if it worked, please mark this as the accepted answer, so the question will be marked as answered and for other users with a similar question to easily find the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set footer fixed to bottom of the page no matter how much content is available in your page. The footer will remain at the bottom of your browser window by using below given css code.

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```