# How to make element stick on top when scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a page I need help with, I have the HTML and CSS ready, all I want is to make the element come to the top after I scroll down a bit, and there have to be more than 5 screens than I need to come to top as I keep scrolling

I can't find a solution so need help

Here's a link of what I need, this is exactly what I want
https://www.blackrock.com/corporate#intro

Comment: Please show us an example of your code that you tried to implement. The community will not provide final code without your own effort.

Comment: position: sticky;

Comment: By "come to top" do you mean "bring to front" as in the z-order? Or do you mean y position?

Comment: Hi here is what you are looking for https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/ custmize your style according to your need then for animation use uikit, scrollspy or try this https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Comment: Your question doesn't match the link you've provided.. what exactly do you want to do? Make a div stick when scrolling, or create several sections that change when you scroll up and down?

Comment: By to front I meant the z-index order, so that you can see only that current screen, basically I just needed something like the website I attached

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

The CSS property you need is `position: sticky` means that this element would be in it's respective `relative` position until you scroll down enough and it reached the top (if you set its `top: 0`) and would then "stick" to the top as if it instantly changed it's position to `position: fixed`. Enjoy

The following code could help you achieve your desired behavior:

```
.sticky-container {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

If it is a container that takes up the entire width then also add `width: 100%` and a certain fixed height in pixels to see the container.

If you want to have the element stay in a certain position in default when the user just entered the website you probably would need `position: fixed` instead of sticky. You could take a look at a similar solution for position fixed [here with a demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041268/how-to-make-the-footer-fixed-through-scrolling/58041349#58041349)